# Not getting correct result for variable in sas dataset

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the below code for average:

```
    proc means data = join_mkt_sort;
    by PRODUCT YEAR_MONTH_NUM;
    var encount_prod;
    output out = temp1 mean(encount_prod) = avg;  
    run;
```

while in the html it shows the correct mean in decimal like : 1.2049, but in the dataset its showing as 1 only while for other variables its doing correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a format issue - verify what format the variable is assigned in the dataset.  It may be assigned a format that does not allow for decimals.

```
proc datasets lib=work;
modify temp1;
format avg BEST32.;
run;
```